# Manage Creative Commons works and their redistribution

Tags: open-source, reference-management, digital-asset-management

I want to keep the overview about [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/) licensed content I redistribute, so I can regularly check if the required attribution is still intact and the place doesn’t become commercial (in case of `NC`).

While this could easily be done with a simple list of links, I want to find a tool that *does more*. I don’t require all the following features, I just want to find the tool that comes closest (and at best welcomes feature requests).

For each *work* (an image, a video, a document, etc.), let me enter the **work’s metadata**:

- the specific CC license
- all the fields required for attribution (which might depend on the chosen CC license), with the ability to mark fields as "not specified" (and not just to leave these empty)

And also the **metadata of my redistribution**:

- URLs of the places I redistributed the work, together with dates of my publication
- (unless `ND` is used) the modifications/derivations I made

(Or, hey, automatically parse them from the page when the author used semantic markup.)

And when I entered all this, why not help with attribution? **Generate attribution snippets** (e.g., in HTML, possibly with RDFa) which I can copy-paste.

And to be on the safe side, allow to keep **backups**

- of the work (in case it gets deleted)
- of the original author’s license/copyright notice (in case the author changes their mind and removes the license), e.g., by screenshotting or saving the HTML page.

A nice side effect of this: I now have a (local) database of works which I’d love to be able to **search** with filters.

---

A solution must be **FLOSS**. It can be a self-hosted web app or a local client (no OS restriction).

Comment: Why not use a citation management software, like the many based on bibtex?

Comment: @Nemo: Might certainly be possible (I have almost no experience with them); but I guess they would typically not provide a way to capture the metadata of my redistributions (i.e., one work may be published by me on different sites, with different modifications), or would I do this by adding a reference to a text document (as if I would cite) and add the modification description in plain text next to the citation?

Comment: different versions of a same document are something they should be able to handle, as many scientific papers have preprint + actual publication + unofficial archive(s) + institutional archive...

Comment: @Nemo: I see. If you happen to know a good solution/workflow for such a citation management software, feel free to create an answer :)